# cPanel.net hosting. Website cannot be viewed by others

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting

I hosted a website on cpanel.net and created a subdomain. "test.example.com". The website is viewable on my computer but cannot be viewed by others. What could be the problem? I'm suspecting it's a DNS problem but I cannot or does not know how to configure it with cpanel.net.

Comment: if you can access it then others should do also, guess that if you wait for a couple of days it will spread across DNS of others too.

Comment: Any way, contact the support.

Comment: Assuming you didn't change your computer's host file.. 

How are you configuring your subdomain to point to the right location?